# Error Length Required sending sitemap to Google Search Console

Tags: shell, curl, google-search-console

I have this shell script to submit a new sitemap to Google Search Console API:

```
curl --request PUT \
'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/sc-domain%3Amy-website.com/sitemaps/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.my-website.com%2Fplan-du-site%2Fsitemap%2Fxml%3Fformat%3Dxml' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

But I get this error :

> Error 411 (Length Required)!!1

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: any idea to solve it ?